# How do I delete all non-link files from a folder in Linux?

Tags: linux, libraries, ln

I accidentally copied a bunch of junk into /usr/lib .

How do I rm everything in there except folders and link files?

Comment: Are you sure nothing in it is supposed to be a regular file? Sounds like a good way to get an unbootable system.

Comment: What will the linked files point to ?

Comment: You almost **definitely** don't want to remove everything in /usr/lib.  I would suggest instead doing something along the lines of `find /usr/lib -mtime ...` to find a list of the stuff that was recently modified in /usr/lib, inspecting the list to make sure that it's really what you want to delete, remove it if you feel confident, and then validate all of your packages using your OS's package manager to ensure that nothing important was nuked.  Oh, and make *sure* you have good backups or other recovery method before doing any of this.

Comment: Can't you identify the new files based on their timestamp? Or use the file list from the source of wherever you copied the junk from to identify which files to delete?

Comment: Before deleting any files from there you should ensure that they do not belong to a package - you can query most package managers to figure out which package owns a file.

Comment: Okay thank-you.  ldconfig never used to throw out errors about this directory before dumping in it.  So I was assuming that it is "safe" to delete the files that were dumped in there that it now complains about "not a link file"?  Do I have this right?

Answer (score 0):

[XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) aside, the answer to your ostensible question ("How do I rm everything in [a directory] except folders and link files?") is:

```
find /path/to/directory -not -type d -and -not -type l -exec rm {} +
```

Be *very very* careful with this.  You probably want to execute it without the `-exec` clause before running the full thing.

Answer (score 0):

I wound up making a back-up of my /usr/lib and then deleted all the non-link files.  So far everything seems to be working fine again.